# CarrierWave cache_dir finding nil for model's belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, carrierwave

I have a quick question about the way CarrierWave interacts with the model's associations---or, in my case, the way CarrierWave doesn't. I have one model that `belongs_to` another, and I'd like to use a datum from the owner to set CarrierWave's `cache_dir` and `store_dir`. But I'm finding that when I call something like `model.other_model.attribute`, I get a NoMethodError saying that the nil class doesn't have `attribute`.

That's translated as best I can into *language* language; here's the actual code:

```
# app/models/correction.rb
class Correction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :submission, inverse_of: :corrections
  belongs_to :contract, inverse_of: :corrections

  mount_uploader :pdf, CorrectionsUploader
end

# app/models/contract.rb
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, inverse_of: :contracts
  belongs_to :submission, inverse_of: :contract
  has_many :corrections, inverse_of: :contract

  mount_uploader :pdf, ContractUploader
end

# app/uploaders/corrections_uploader.rb
class CorrectionsUploader < FogCorrectionsUploader
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "corrections/#{model.contract.legal_name}/#{model.contract.titles}"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "/www/website.com/_www/shared/submissions/corrections/#{model.contract.legal_name}/#{model.contract.titles}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(pdf)
  end
  # ...some processing directives that don't seem relevant...
end
```

The controller gets a `submission_id` and `contract_id` from the form, and calls `Correction.new` with those and the other `correction_params`, which just as you'd expect triggers CarrierWave, which then throws an error due to the nilness of `model.contract`.

Since ORM is still sort of a dark continent to me, I tried firing up a Rails console and doing this, and didn't have any trouble:

```
2.0.0 :002 > test_correction = Correction.new({contract_id: 18, submission_id: 161})
    => #<Correction id: nil, submission_id: 161, contract_id: 18, pdf: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, comment: nil, delivered: nil>
2.0.0 :003 > test_correction.submission
    D, [2013-10-12T21:14:31.352684 #1758] DEBUG -- :   Submission Load (15.3ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "submissions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 161]]
    => #<Submission id: 161, title: ...>
```

So it seems like I'm missing something---no doubt something silly---about CarrierWave, but of course I'm not sure. I have no doubt this'll wind up being embarrassingly obvious, but I'd be really deeply grateful for any suggestions that anyone has. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the difference between cache_dir and store_dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else with similar trouble should come across this, I discovered that the fault was in my forms. I'd placed `hidden_field`s for `contract_id` and `submission_id` at the very *end* of the form, after the upload button, and at the very end of the strong-parameters `permit()` call. Apparently *that* was tripping it up, as Rails was trying to process the parameters in the order that it received them and it was getting to the uploader before it had assigned values for `contract_id` and `submission_id`.